# Wifi reconnecting very often

Tags: wireless

I'm new user of ubuntu and unix/linux os.

I have been using Ubuntu for about 1.5 years. All was fine until a week ago. Every few minutes my wifi connection restarts.

I have not install any hardware/drivers/software during this time except for the usual updates from Ubuntu software centre.

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, GNOME 3.36.8.

Here is a copy of the log:

```
wlp7s0: deauthenticating from 04:d9:f5:eb:07:f0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

wlp7s0: deauthenticated from 04:d9:f5:eb:07:f0 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
```

Please help me as I can't fix this problem by myself.

Comment: First thing to do is reboot the router.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.